# VBA Selenium - Interact with a chrome that is already open

Tags: vba, selenium-chromedriver

I have an open chrome instance whitch use to login on internal site, now I what to interact with it in order open a new tab and navegating to another link.

```
Option Explicit

Dim cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver


Sub UsingTabs()

    Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    cd.Start
    cd.Get "https://curyempreendimentos.sienge.com.br/sienge/8/index.html#/"
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't use selenium to grab hold of an already open chrome instance. Because... security. You can use selenium to grab a handle of another window in the same chrome instance launched by the current selenium automation. Your code is launching chrome so simply SwitchTo next window or use js command via driver to switch tabs.

Comment: I just SwitchToNextWindow and this solved the problem. tks

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it with Selenium driver for Chrome.
Locate your chrome.exe directory and copy and paste the line below into the address bar.

chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222

Then copy the following code into a vba module, execute it, and it will allow you to manipulate the existing chrome session that you created.

```
Dim chromeBrowser As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub existingChromeSession()
      Set chromeBrowser = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
      chromeBrowser.SetCapability "debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222"
      chromebrowser.Get("https://www.google.com")
End Sub
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said but nothing happened. Program seems to got stuck in a loop (or waiting for something). Non of my chrome already opened tabs navigates to "www.google.com" nor the one which opened in Debugger Mode.

Comment: Everything works fine here