# Retrieve a URL from an open webpage

Tags: excel, vba, url

I am running an Excel worksheet alongside an open webpage.  I navigate to the webpages independently from Excel.  Once I get to a page I am interested in, I want to run a macro in Excel to retrieve the URL to put into a hyperlink.  I don't want the macro to open a new browser window, just use the one already open.  How is this done in VBA?  I have been doing this manually with copy and paste, but that is tedious.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which web browser? Do you have only one tab open?

Comment: I am using Edge, but could switch to another if it is easier.  I always have multiple tabs and only want the macro to look at the active tab.

Comment: Would using Selenium Basic for VBA make this easier?

Comment: I think that’s probably the easiest way to go

Comment: How is that coded?  I can only find examples that open a webpage first.  I just want to use an already open page.

Comment: I've never done that but see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70351508/vba-selenium-interact-with-a-chrome-that-is-already-open

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't require the use of Selenium ... but it certainly isn't 'production' code relying on the use of SendKeys ... it will work for your personal use but not more than that.

Also, this solution needs your VBA project to have a reference to the 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library' - if your VBA project already includes a UserForm then it will already have this reference ... you're good to go! If not, either ...

1. Directly add the reference: in the VBE menu, Tools > References, find 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library', put a check next to it then click OK. Or,
2. Add then remove a UserForm: in the VBE menu, Insert > UserForm, then remove it: right click on the added UserForm in the Project Window, select 'Remove UserForm1' and select 'No' to export ... the reference to the library is left behind when the UserForm is deleted.

Once you've added the reference, then add the following Function:

```
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose: Get the URL shown in active tab of the Edge browser
' Parameter outUrl (String): Will be updated with the URL if successful
' Returns (Boolean): True if successful, false otherwise
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function TryGetUrl(ByRef outUrl As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo errExit
    
    ' change to "Chrome" if desired
    AppActivate "Edge", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    Application.SendKeys "^l^c", True
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    
    AppActivate Application.Caption
    
    ' needs a reference to the 'Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library'
    With New MSForms.DataObject
        .GetFromClipboard
        outUrl = .GetText
    End With
    
    TryGetUrl = True
    Exit Function

errExit:
End Function
```

A usage example:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim url As String
    If TryGetUrl(url) Then
        MsgBox "URL shown is " & url
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not get URL"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works well the first time I use the macro.  The second attempt opens the previously used URL, and its source code, then retrieves that URL.  The new URL never gets pickup up.  Any thoughts?

Comment: This code will only work if you have only 1 Edge window open ... that window can have multiple tabs (and it will get the URL from the active tab), but if you have multiple Edge Windows open then the URL will come an 'arbitrarily' selected Edge window - see [AppActivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/appactivate-statement)

Comment: I only have one Edge window open, with multiple tabs.  But, it doesn't work correctly on successive uses as indicated above.

Comment: This is how I used the code you provided.

Comment: Sub Add_Hyperlink()
'
' Add_Hyperlink Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+K
    Dim url As String
    If TryGetUrl(url) Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=url
    Else
        MsgBox "Could not get URL"
    End If
   
End Sub

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't figure out how to paste the VBA code in formatted.

Comment: Your code should work fine. So TryGetUrl() just copies the URL shown in the address bar of Edge. When running the code, check that the URL shown is for the 'new' tab ie the one you're expecting to be copied.